# RegEx for URLs with a constant the end

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the right expression to find url path that end with a constant.

I.e 'profile' a costant:

```
www.site.org/profile    => true
www.site.org/profile    => true
www.erty.org/profile/1  => true
www.site.org/xyzdddd    => false
www.ssss.org/profile    => true
```

This is my starter code (all url http/s):

```
/(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/g
```

I miss the control of a constant to the end with any slash.

Comment: what do you mean "constant"?

Comment: Why is `www.site.org/profile` accepted while `www.site.org/xyzdddd` not accepted?

Comment: Ok, 'profile' is the constant for example.

Comment: Then why is `www.erty.org/profile/1` valid?

Comment: Because it has the constant 'profile' present.

Comment: Then use a lookahead: [`/^https?:\/\/(?=.*\/profile(?:\/|$))(\w+:?\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/m49R2d/1) (to see if it works, do not copy/paste from here, go to regex101.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to match those strings that contain `/profile/` (or `/profile` at the end) path part. You may check that with a *positive lookahead*:

```
/^https?:\/\/(?=.*\/profile(?:\/|$))(\w+:?\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?$/
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m49R2d/1).

The lookahead `(?=.*\/profile(?:\/|$))` means that after any 0+ chars (`.*`) there must be `/profile`, followed with `/` or end of string.